# Error: cannot convert from 'int' to 'fileReader.Street' when checking if item is already in hashset

Tags: c#, hashset

I am creating a hashset of "street" like this:

```
public HashSet<Street> streets= new HashSet<Street>();

Straat tmpStreet = new Street(tmpId, tmpNiscode, fileData[2]);
if (!Streets.Contains(tmpNiscode))
{
     Streets.Add(tmpStreet);
}
```

However, when I want to check if the street is already in the hashset, I get an error:

> cannot convert from 'int' to 'fileReader.Street'

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `Streets` hashset is waiting for type `Street` not an int like `tmpNiscode` you're using with `Contains` method.

Comment: Well, obviously `tmpNiscode` is not what you think it is. It seems to be an integer, but your HashSet containts `Street`s ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating a HashSet of type Street and then you're trying to check if this Set of Streets does contain an integer *tmpNiscode*.

In your case you could check if the street is already contained in the set like this:

```
public HashSet<Street> streets= new HashSet<Street>();

Straat tmpStreet = new Street(tmpId, tmpNiscode, fileData[2]);

if (!streets.Contains(tmpStreet))
{
    streets.Add(tmpStreet);
}
```

To get a correct hashcode for a class you also have to override the *GetHashCode* function of your class. You can look this up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods?view=vs-2019)

Comment: this doesn't work because there is no address with the same NISCODE because that is auto-increment. but what I need is to get every street 1time, now i got it multiple times..